Are "мне больше нравится" and "я предпочитаю" synonymous?
My flashcards have мне больше нравится translated as I prefer and я предпочитаю as I favor. My understanding is that these are essentially synonymous. I suppose I have two questions:

Is there any semantic difference between мне больше нравится апельсиновый сок and я предпочитаю апельсиновый сок?
Is there a scenario where it makes more sense to use мне больше нравится than я предпочитаю, and vice-versa?


Мне больше нравится means "I like (something) better"; я предпочитаю means "I prefer".
You might like soda and not like orange juice, but when you have to choose, you would still prefer orange juice to soda (for instance, because you think it's healthier).
In this case, you would say газировка мне нравится больше, чем апельсиновый сок, and я предпочитаю апельсиновый сок газировке, and both statements would be true.

So, Мне больше нравится implies that the subject does like the object to some degree and that the object is preferable to some alternative? (I like football more than hockey, but I like them both.)

And я предпочитаю does not necessarily imply that the subject does like the object to some degree, but it does mean that the object is preferable to some alternative, whether the subject likes it or not? (I prefer having a stomach ache to having a headache.)

@DavidChopin: yes and yes.

I agree with Quassnoi, and your own additional comments are very good. However,I have to add something: your average Russian native speaker will use 'мне больше нравится' more often in his everyday communication, because it's more colloquial (and not because of the subtleties of meaning; as you mentioned correctly, both expressions are essentially synonymous). I don't say that you will never hear 'я предпочитаю' in the street, but it sounds definitely more literary, and it's used frequently in a formal and/or polite speech ( e.g. I can easily imagine a waiter in the restaurant, asking 'Какой десерт вы предпочитаете?' because of this additional degree of politeness). It is more formal than the English translation of it, 'I prefer', which is used so easily and so often by native English speakers; and I think it's important to remember about this difference. Hope it helps.

Thanks, this is super helpful!
